# Replacing values in a column for a subset of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` having multiple columns. I would like to replace the value in a column called `Discriminant`. Now this value needs to only be replaced for a few rows, whenever a condition is met in another column called `ids`. I tried various methods; The most common method seems to be using the `.loc` method, but for some reason it doesn't work for me.

Here are the variations that I am unsuccessfully trying:

`encodedid` - variable used for condition checking

`indices` - variable used for subsetting the `dataframe` (starts from zero)

**Variation 1:**

```
df[df.ids == encodedid].loc[df.ids==encodedid, 'Discriminant'].values[indices] = 'Y'
```

**Variation 2:**

```
df[df['ids'] == encodedid].iloc[indices,:].set_value('questionid','Discriminant', 'Y')
```

**Variation 3:**

```
df.loc[df.ids==encodedid, 'Discriminant'][indices] = 'Y'
```

`Variation 3` particularly has been disappointing in that most posts on SO tend to say it should work but it gives me the following error:

```
ValueError: [ 0  1  2  3  5  6  7  8 10 11 12 13 14 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23] not contained in the index
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what is indices? can you print it? not sure what you are trying to acheive, also show us a small print of you df

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are slicing too much. try something like this:

```
indexer = df[df.ids == encodedid].index
df.loc[indexer, 'Discriminant'] = 'Y'
```

`.loc[]` needs an index list and a column list. you can set the value of that slice easily using `=` 'what you need'

looking at your problem you might want to set that for 2 columns at the same time such has:

```
indexer = df[df.ids == encodedid].index
column_list = ['Discriminant', 'questionid']

df.loc[indexer, column_list] = 'Y'
```

Comment: added an example for 2 columns at the same time

Comment: IMO `df.loc[(df.ids == encodedid), 'Discriminant'] = 'Y' (if "encodedid" is a scalar value) or `df.loc[df.ids.isin(encodedid), 'Discriminant'] = 'Y'` (if "encodedid" is a list-like) should be enough

Comment: @Patthebug, can you post reproducible sample and desired data sets (5 rows for each should be enough)? And what is `encodedid` - is it a list or a scalar value?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this. I don't have a dataframe to test it, but...

```
df['Discriminant'] = np.where(df['ids'] == 'some_condition', 'replace', df['Discriminant'])
```